# make images same size without manipulating their size individually?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to put some logos in a row and a div wraps each logo the problem is that When I am giving a specific width to all the logo wrapper Divs some are becoming small and vice versa (I know it is due to the Dimension of the Logs {Images}) But is there any way we can make all the logos look even by on a single CSS property.

I hope I am able to clarify the question.

Any help is highly appreciated!

```css
.logos-container{
    background: #ddd;
}
.logos-container .client-logo{
    width: 120px;
}
.logos-container .client-logo img{
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 
 <div class=" container logos-container d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center flex-wrap px-4 py-3">
            
            <div class="client-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/nasa-6.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="client-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/microsoft.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="client-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/ibm.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="client-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/dell-computer.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="client-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/hp-2.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="client-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/coca-cola-6.svg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
 
 
 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `object-fit: contain;` would be the best bet for a task like this—as shown in one of the answers. That said, it would only get you so far without manipulating individual logos as needed. Logos can be vertically or horizontally long, and either square or circle in shape. Even within the same shape, the wordmark can be bigger or small (e.g. compare `Nasa` vs `HP`, and `Coca-Cola` vs `IBM`). For the best optical consistency, you might still want to consider adjusting individual logo styles either via CSS or image files themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) to let the browser calculate the containing scale ratio for the image data size:

```css
.client-logo img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

or use `cover` instead of `contain` if you want the images to fit perfectly without blanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just give a specific height to the images. We cannot apply equal width because of the different sizes of logos so let that be 100%.

```
.logos-container .client-logo img{
  height:50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set a height instead of a width:

```css
.logos-container{
    background: #ddd;
}

.logos-container .client-logo img{
    height: 80px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 
 <div class=" container logos-container d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center flex-wrap px-4 py-3">
            
            <div class="client-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/nasa-6.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="client-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/microsoft.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="client-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/ibm.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="client-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/dell-computer.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="client-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/hp-2.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="client-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/coca-cola-6.svg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
 
 
 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```